# How is the server getting Object Object params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a situation where somehow users are submitting a form and the server is getting this as params.

```
HTTP Method: POST
* Parameters : {"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>{","=>{"object Object"=>nil}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}, "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"admin/episodes"}
```

We are doing a normal form_for

```
<%= form_for(@object, remote: true, html: {id: 'new_obj_form'} ) do |object| %>

<%= object.label(:title, 'Title') %>
<%= object.text_field(:title, class: 'has_default') %>
 ....

<input type="submit" class="btn" id="submit" value="Save Details" data-disable-with="Saving Details"/>

<% end %>
```

Any reason why the server would be getting all the object json as the server params?